# How to get CMake find freeglut on windows?

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, glut, freeglut

I am working on Windows and I would like to create an OS independent project in CMake. I also would like to use OpenGL with freeglut.

My *CMakeLists.txt* so far looks like this:

```
project (visualizer)

set(GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR "C:/Program Files (x86)/freeglut/include")
set(OPENGL_LIBRARY_DIR "C:/Program Files (x86)/freeglut/lib")

# GLUT
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR})
if(NOT GLUT_FOUND)
    message(ERROR "GLUT not found!")
endif(NOT GLUT_FOUND)

# OpenGL
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
if(NOT OPENGL_FOUND)
    message(ERROR "OPENGL not found!")
endif(NOT OPENGL_FOUND)

add_executable(visu visualizer.cpp)
target_link_libraries(visu ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARY})
```

I have to explicitly define the paths for `GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR` and `OPENGL_LIBRARY_DIR`, otherwise cmake will give me this error:

> CMake Error at C:/Program
>   Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137
>   (message):   Could NOT find GLUT (missing: GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR)

As far as I know this should be handled by `findglut.cmake`. I mean, I do not have the expertise to find out where it would search for the lib, but I think this part of the `findglut.cmake` supposed to do it:

```
if (WIN32)
  find_path( GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES GL/glut.h
    PATHS  ${GLUT_ROOT_PATH}/include )
  find_library( GLUT_glut_LIBRARY_RELEASE NAMES glut glut32 freeglut
    PATHS
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARY_DIR}
    ${GLUT_ROOT_PATH}/Release
    )
  find_library( GLUT_glut_LIBRARY_DEBUG NAMES freeglutd
    PATHS
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARY_DIR}
    ${GLUT_ROOT_PATH}/Debug
    )
  mark_as_advanced(GLUT_glut_LIBRARY_RELEASE GLUT_glut_LIBRARY_DEBUG)
  select_library_configurations(GLUT_glut)
else ()
```

**My actual question is:** Where should I put the freeglut files so CMake will find them without any additional effort?

Comment: Before `find_package(GLUT)` add line `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Program Files (x86)/freeglut")`. This is how one may hint CMake about locating of the package for `find_package` be able to find it.